# i want to display {message} first and after displaynext letter is completed i want to display {nouns}

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display ${nouns} after displaying ${message}. The message displays according to function of displaynextletter() but the nouns is displaying as soon as i get json.response

I tried everything to my knowledge but still either it is displaying as soon as i get json response or it is not displaying.

Please help me this javascript code.

````
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Autochat Bot</title>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.5/flowbite.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flowbite/1.6.5/flowbite.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
    #suggestionslink{
      justify-content: flex-start;
      background-color: #075DB3E9;
      color: #fff;
      padding-left: 1.0rem ;
      width: min(95%, 850px);
      height: `${noun.length * 20}px`;
      overflow: auto;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .box {
      width: min(95%, 800px);
      height: 100vh;
      margin-top: 85px;
    }

    .bottom {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
      padding-bottom: 5%;
      background-color: white;
      width: min(95%, 800px);
    }

    .message {
      margin: 20px;
    }

    .usermessagediv {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-left: 20%;
    }

    .usermessage {
      background-color: #097df1;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 0.5rem 0.875rem;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .appmessagediv {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      margin-right: 20%;
    }

    .appmessage {
      background-color: #e5e5ea;
      color: #000;
      padding: 0.5rem 0.875rem;
      border-radius: 20px;
    }

    .upper {
      max-height: 100%;
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 170px;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    .upper::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0 !important;
    }

    #sendbtn:disabled {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .downwarning {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 5px;
      font-size: 90%;
      color: gray;
    }

    nav {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      padding: 3px;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #80808057;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="upper" id="upperid">
        <span class="downwarning">Type your message in box below.</span>
      </div>

      <div class="bottom">
        <form id="userinputform">
          <label for="chat" class="sr-only">Your message</label>
          <div class="flex items-center px-3 py-2 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 dark:bg-gray-700">
            <textarea id="userinput" rows="1"
              class="block mx-4 p-2.5 w-full text-sm text-gray-900 bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-300 focus:ring-blue-500 focus:border-blue-500 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-blue-500 dark:focus:border-blue-500"
              placeholder=" Your message..." required></textarea>
            <button type="submit"
              class="inline-flex justify-center p-2 text-blue-600 rounded-full cursor-pointer hover:bg-blue-100 dark:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-600"
              id="sendbtn">
              <svg aria-hidden="true" class="w-6 h-6 rotate-90" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path
                  d="M10.894 2.553a1 1 0 00-1.788 0l-7 14a1 1 0 001.169 1.409l5-1.429A1 1 0 009 15.571V11a1 1 0 112 0v4.571a1 1 0 00.725.962l5 1.428a1 1 0 001.17-1.408l-7-14z">
                </path>
              </svg>
              <span class="sr-only">Send message</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>

        <span class="downwarning"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function scrollToBottom() {
      var div = document.getElementById("upperid");
      div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
    }
    scrollToBottom()

     async function callApi(noun) {
        const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ data: noun }),
        });

        let json = await response.json();
        console.log('resp', json);
        if (json.response) {
            let message = json.message;
            let upperdiv = document.getElementById("upperid");
            upperdiv.innerHTML = upperdiv.innerHTML + `<div class="message">
                <div class="appmessagediv">
                    <div class="appmessage">
                        ${message}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;
        }
    }

    document
      .getElementById("userinputform")
      .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        formsubmitted();
      });

    const formsubmitted = async () => {
      let userinput = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
      let sendbtn = document.getElementById("sendbtn");
      let userinputarea = document.getElementById("userinput");
      let upperdiv = document.getElementById("upperid");

      upperdiv.innerHTML =
        upperdiv.innerHTML +
        `<div class="message">
                <div class="usermessagediv">
                        <div class="usermessage">
                            ${userinput}
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>`;

      sendbtn.disable = true;
      userinput.disable = true;
      scrollToBottom();
      document.getElementById("userinput").value = "";

      var delay = 1000;
      var vals = ["Retriving", "Analysing"];
      var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
      for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        set(vals[i], i * delay);
      }

      function set(v, d) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          setInterval(function () {
            input.setAttribute("placeholder", v);
          }, delay * vals.length);
        }, d);
      }

      const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/data", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',

        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ data: userinput })
      });
        
      
      let json = await response.json();
      let link = document.createElement('a')
      let noun=json.nouns
        let suggestionslink = document.getElementById('suggestionslink')
        let inde=0
        function displayNextLetter() {
          scrollToBottom()
          if (inde < noun.length) {
            suggestionslink.innerHTML = suggestionslink.innerHTML + noun[inde];
            inde++;
            setTimeout(displayNextLetter, 30);
          } else {
            suggestionslink.removeAttribute('id')
            sendbtn.disabled = false
            userinputarea.disabled = false
          }
        }  
        

      console.log('resp', json)
      document.getElementById('userinput').placeholder = "Your message..."
      if (json.response) {
        let message = json.message
        upperdiv.innerHTML = upperdiv.innerHTML + `<div class="message">
              <div class="appmessagediv">
                  <div class="appmessage" id="temp">
                
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div  style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top:20px;">
                  <p> <a href="#">
                 ${noun.map((item,index) => {
    return `<div class='appmessage' id="suggestionslink" style="margin-right: 2px;margin-bottom: 10px; cursor: pointer;" onclick="callApi('${item}')">${item}</div>`
}).join('')}
                 
                  </p>
              </div>
              </div>
          </div>`
 
        document.getElementById('suggestionslink').style.height = 'auto';
        let temp = document.getElementById('temp')
        let index = 0
        function displayNextLetter() {
          scrollToBottom()
          if (index < message.length) {
            temp.innerHTML = temp.innerHTML + message[index];
            index++;
            setTimeout(displayNextLetter, 30);
          } else {
            temp.removeAttribute('id')
            sendbtn.disabled = false
            userinputarea.disabled = false
          }
        }
        displayNextLetter()
        scrollToBottom()

      }
      else {
        let message = json.message
        upperdiv.innerHTML = upperdiv.innerHTML +
          `<div class="message">
              <div class="appmessagediv">
                  <div class="appmessage"  style="border: 1px solid red;">
                    ${message}

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>`
        sendbtn.disabled = false
        userinputarea.disabled = false
      }
      scrollToBottom()
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>```
````